# Facebook sharer.php 500 error

Tags: ajax, facebook

At the moment I am attempting to share a link on Facebook without the use of JavaScript or a Facebook app id.

Previously I could have a hyperlink to: `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=urlhere` and Facebook would scrape for og:tags and allow me to share a site.

At the moment I'm encountering a 500 error when I attempt to submit a link that has not previously been crawled by Facebook.

**How to reproduce the bug**

- Find a new link that you're certain hasn't been crawled by FB. Good examples of this are tweets.
- Attempt to visit `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php` and paste in your link
- Submit the form and see the post preview
- Attempt to submit the post
- If you've used a fresh URL there is a good chance you'll get a 500 error similar to: `POST https://www.facebook.com/ajax/sharer/submit_page/ 500 (Internal Server Error)`
- If you refresh the page and attempt to submit the same URL again, it will post successfully.
- Once the link has been crawled by Facebook, it works without problems

Anyone having similar problems with this method of sharing?

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid Facebook bug, see https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/795945327148024/.