# Rails App runs well, but facebook gives me 500 error when I share the website link in facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

My website is at http://www.siliconstone.com, and it runs well without any error. However when I PASTE the link above on facebook page, the facebook gives me 500 error: **"We're sorry but something went wrong (500)"**

It is weird enough if i TYPE the link into the facebook comment box, there is no error at all.

Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: What do you have in logs of your website? Their should be a problem

Comment: I found an error in the log about the locale setting and i fixed it. but the 500 error on facebook is still there. I found another error about a routing problem of a subfolder image missing, maybe the error is from there. let me check it again.

Comment: something to do with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29266319/facebook-sharer-php-500-error?rq=1

Comment: Missing image shouldn't really affect it, probably there could be a cache a links, try again a day later, for example, or change parameters of link

Comment: Put it through the debut tool, to refresh Facebook‘s cache. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: Thank you guys, it's the Facebook cache thing I think. I tried a few days later and everything went normal.